# Сокращение слов "максимум" и "минимум"

Tags: аббревиатуры

Как правильно сократить слово "максимум" и слово "минимум". Подскажите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В научно-техническом тексте обычно используют международные сокращения ***max***  и ***min***. В обычном, не научном, тексте лучше не сокращать вовсе, причин для того нет.

Что касается всякого рода словарей сокращений, особенно онлайновых, то они не являются нормирующим источником, а лишь фиксируют, что кто-то когда-то подобное сокращение сделал. Причем правильные (нормативные) сокращения туда часто не попадают по причине своей очевидности.

Comment: Morkovkin, во-первых -этот словарь рекомендует Грамота.ру, во-вторых, " причин для того нет".  не ответ. Эти сокращения представлены и в других словарях.

Comment: Во-первых, "Грамота" - не аргумент, тем более  что ничего она не "рекомендует", а просто дает ссылку, извольте не передергивать. Во-вторых,  " причин для того нет" - вполне себе ответ. Не надо делать того, для чего нет причин - это вообще достаточно разумный принцип, в некоторых случаях, даже главенствующий.

Comment: раз дает ссылку, значит рекомендует. Это вы передергиваете. Просто так она давать ссылку не будет. Во-вторых, такое сокращение представлено на их сайте. И если вам что-то  не нравится, это значит, такое сокращение  не стоит использует..

Comment: @Серж *такое сокращение представлено на их сайте* - в качестве чего представлено? *раз дает ссылку, значит рекомендует* - нет. Это ваше личное мнение. Ссылку сожно давать по самым разным поводам. Вопрос для меня закрыт. Вы выдаете желаемое за действительное.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно:

- [*макс.*](http://sokr.ru/card/25693sbe5e789e/)
- [*мин.*](http://sokr.ru/card/27048s1d40b69c/) или [*миним.*](http://sokr.ru/card/27095s4c020b19/)

Подробно о других сокращений можно посмотреть на [sokr.ru](http://www.sokr.ru/) и здесь: [ПРАВИЛА ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ СОКРАЩЕНИЙ В ТЕКСТАХ ДОКУМЕНТОВ](http://doc-style.ru/SPR/?id=1.10)

Comment: мин. миним. — это минимум с миниморумом?

Comment: @shampar, исправил. Ждём утверждения.

Comment: @Серж, спасибо за замечание. Глянул в словарь — действительно есть, но это две разные аббревиатуры одного слова. Предпринял вторую попытку.

Comment: @Arhad Как программист - программисту. Вы бы лучше исправляли по принципу достоверности информации, вы же знаете, как создаются подобные онлайновые словари.

Comment: @Morkovkin, информацию я оставил авторскую, отформатировал только для более простого восприятия. Так что пусть задача определения достоверности лежит на Серже.

Comment: @Arhad, я видел историю правок. Вопрос восприятия - субъективен. Впрочем, не смею настаивать.

Comment: @Morkovkin, я уже сказал, что этот словарь рекомендует Грамота.ру, да и потом, эти сокращения общепринятые, сомневаться не в чем. В том же виде эти сокращения представлены и в других словарях.

Comment: @Серж А я Вам уже ответил, что Грамота  1) не рекомендут 2) не аргумент. С "другими словарями" разбирайтесь отдельно. И не наде путать использованные в словарях сокращения с нормативными на все другие типы текстов. Вы даже правку вопроса провели так, что в глаза бросается.